# How to parse encoding from WebClient Response?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing

I get the Content-Type of a page trought a `WebClient.ResponseHeaders`. If I print it with:

```
client.ResponseHeaders["Content-Type"]
```

I get somethings like:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

so I want to get it (if there is). Else set a default one. This is my actual code:

```
var KeysParsed = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(client.ResponseHeaders["Content-Type"].Replace(" ", "").Replace(";", "&"));
var charset = ((KeysParsed["charset"] != null) ? KeysParsed["charset"] : "UTF-8");
```

I don't know why, but it looks not so flexible. What can you suggest about?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel? See [System.Net.Mime.ContentType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mime.contenttype.aspx):

```
var contentType = new ContentType(client.ResponseHeaders["Content-Type"]);
Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", contentType.MediaType, contentType.CharSet);

var charset = (contentType.CharSet ?? "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Didn't know about that ContentType object ;) Thank you very much!

Comment: There's also the more powerful `System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue` (.NET 4.5) and `Microsoft.Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue` (ASP.NET Core and .NET Core) types which both provide `Parse` methods.

Answer (score -1):

Try with WebClient.Encoding  after gettting response. Please look at [**WebClient.Encoding**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.encoding.aspx)

Comment: Encoding might not be the same as a charset for the whole request.